# C# Можно ли это запускать асинхронно?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь понять как работает `Tasks` и `async/await`

Вроде всё получается заставить работать асинхронно, а эту строчку нет(

```
Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Вы похожи на человека с молотком, для которого все выглядит гвоздями...

Comment: @Сергей сейчас, так оно и есть, поэтому и задаю вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы заставить работать что-то синхронное асинхронно, оборачиваем это в:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
// какой-то синхронный код
});
```

Или так (из комментов, да так и правильнее, пожалуй):

```
await Task.Run(()=>
{
// какой-то синхронный код
});
```

Но делать так следует редко и осторожно - по сути только долгие операции (IO и вычисления) и то в случае если нет асинхронной версии... Есть еще куча нюансов и проблем - это решение сильно в лоб. Короче можно, но вам не надо.

Comment: Можно ответ еще дополнить вариантом `await Task.Run() => {/** some code */}`